# Kendo DataSource() sorting multiple fields

Tags: kendo-ui

Im trying to sort my datasource my multiple fields but it doesnt work. 
Here's my code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: notifURL
    },
    pageSize: 30,
    sort: [{ field: "ID", dir: "desc" },
            { field: "Time", dir: "desc" }]
});
```

Comment: You code seems ok. What actually doesn't works?

Comment: A small sample of your data, how you expect it to sort and how it is actually sorting will help us give you a decent answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/sort):

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
    { name: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
    { name: "Ham", category: "Food" }
  ],
  sort: [
    // sort by "category" in descending order and then by "name" in ascending order
    { field: "category", dir: "desc" },
    { field: "name", dir: "asc" }
  ]
});
dataSource.fetch(function(){
  var data = dataSource.view();
  console.log(data[1].name); // displays "Coffee"
});
</script>
```